# How to prevent Highchart from severely change declines?

Tags: highcharts

The problem is that, if I try to change the lowest point to somewhere higher, the entire chart will be lowered severely.

How do I adjust each point with no above mentioned issue?

P.S. I use Highchart's Highstock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you are trying to set the 7th point from currently at ~150 to something really high, say 5000? I did not notice any real change in the position of other points if the new value was under 1500 (or something around twice the first point)

Appears that your chart is set to comparison mode, hence, I believe, the default max and min are (100% & -100%) by default, this is w.r.t. to first point of the series. Highcharts would auto adjust these extremes if any of the points were to lie outside this range, you could force an override using [yAxis.min](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.min) & max.

For instance, you can set yAxis.min to -100 and yAxis.max to 100 like this

```
yAxis: {
  min:-100,
  max:100
}
```

Play around with the min and max to get to the values that suits your data the most, do remember these are % comparison to the first point. Any points outside these ranges would not show in the chart.

**[@jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4hML/2/)**

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain in details that what code I should add if I want to set the 7th point to 300.0? When I do that, the 5th point was changed. I don't know much about Highchart. The current code was wrote by someone else.

Comment: Is it possible to make the highest value be as close to the top border as possible? Currently the gap between the top border and the highest value is too large.

Comment: You will need to pre process your data and calculate Ymax as follows. Ymax=(highest/first - 1)*100+5 @Ian y

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you could show a JsFiddle with the actual working code.  Without knowing what exactly is going on with your chart it's difficult to figure out what the issue is and how to fix it.

Have a look at the [yAxis - Highstock API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis), you could potentially make use of `min` or `max` to counteract the scaling.  Again though, without seeing your code it's tough to know.

Comment: Hi, the jsFiddle example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M4hML/). When I try to increase the lowest value (the 7th), the positions of other values are affected and they aren't at where they were at any more.